# span doesn't stay vertically centered inside button in mozilla

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm trying to center a `span` that has `display:block;` inside a `button`

**it works in Chrome and in IE9 but not in Firefox**

Here's the link to it:
http://jsbin.com/adefom/5/edit

anybody knows how to make this span centered (vertically) in firefox ?

Comment: You should not give a `<span>` `display: block;`. That's a `<div>`. Calling it a `<span>` and using CSS to make it behave like a `<div>` is just going to confuse anyone who inherits this code (or confuse yourself, if you come back to it in a few months/years).

Comment: Also, for me, it doesn't look centered in Chrome *or* Firefox. Trying to think about why.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/adefom/8/edit :)

Comment: @DragoonWraith my chrome version 20.0.1132.57 m

Comment: Safari looks like Chrome (makes sense, both are Webkit), but neither's quite centered. Chris's version no longer looks like a button, so I'm not sure that's what you want...

Comment: @Chris if you add height and width to the button it's the same, doesn't matter if you use float:left or display:block

Comment: Don't add height and width the the button. It isn't needed when you're already explicitly sizing the contents.

Comment: @Chris I add margin:auto for the span so that it would be at the center, I have different size buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the hard-coded height and width on `.btn` and give it some `padding`.

```
<button class='btn'>
  <div class='icon'></div>
</button>
```

```
button
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

/* Firefox button padding fix */
button::-moz-focus-inner
{
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.icon
{
  background-color: black;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
}

.btn
{
  padding: 4px;
}
```

The Firefox button padding fix is from [here](http://www.aheadcreative.com/removing-unwanted-button-padding-in-firefox/). Thanks to @Rajesh for finding that one.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/adefom/25/edit) <-- Click!

Comment: it doesn't show the black box this way, and when I add display:block to the span to make it show up it's not centered

Comment: When I add height and width to the button I get the same thing, I guess I just need to use a bigger button (http://jsbin.com/adefom/23/edit), for some reason on firefox 25px button cannot encapsulate a 16px element; it's like ff would have some hidden padding

Comment: found a fix :), http://www.aheadcreative.com/removing-unwanted-button-padding-in-firefox/ ; thnx for helping me to get to the solution

Comment: My, that is weird. +1 for finding that; I'm going to add it to my answer for future-user (hi, future-user!).